# Number Theory Divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was doing some basic number theory exercises and there was this one question that made me stuck.

> Find all positive integers $N$ such that every positive integers $n\leq\sqrt{N}$ divides $N$.

First I tried to divide $N$ into interval in the following way,

$p^2\leq{N}<(p+1)^2$, where $p$ is a positive integers.

Then I tried to find the prime factor for $N$ on some of the first intervals and got some values for $N$ which are $1,2,3,4,6,8,12$, and $24$ (If I didn't miscount).

It seems like there is no more larger value for $N$ as the LCM of the required prime factor of $N$ tend to not being present in the interval. I think it is true but I don't know how to prove it.

Can anyone help me to prove it ? Or maybe there is another method/ways to solve this problem ?

Comment: It may help to think about it this way.  If $m = \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor$, you want $\text{lcm}(1,\ldots, m) < (m+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s look for solutions $N \geq 25$. 
So $N$ is even, let $d$ be the largest integer such that $d^2 \leq N$. Then, if $d$ is odd, $d-2$, $d-1$, $d$ are pairwise coprime integrs that all divide $N$, so their product divides $N$, so $(d+1)^2 > N \geq d(d-1)(d-2)$.

Then, as $N \geq 25$, $d \geq 5$ so $d+1 \leq 1.5(d-1)$, thus $2.25d(d-1) > (d+1)^2 > d(d-1)(d-2)$ so $2.25 > d-2$, thus $d \leq 4$, a contradiction.

So $d$ is even and for the same reason $(d+1)^2 > (d-1)(d-2)(d-3)$. But then, if $d \geq 8$, $d+1 \leq 1.5(d-2)$, so $2.25(d-1)(d-2) > (d-1)(d-2)(d-3)$ so $d-3 < 2.25$, so $d \leq 5$, a contradiction as well.

If finally, $d=6$, $(d-1)(d-2)(d-3)=60 > 49=(d+1)^2$ and we still have our contradiction.

Comment: When d is even, the inequality d+1<=1.5(d-2) is satisfied by all possible d except for d=6. Does this mean we will need to clarify that there is no solution for d=6 in separate way ?

Comment: Oops, miscalculation. We need a separate check indeed. I edited.